# Is there a way to check if a formula's result has changed?

Tags: microsoft-excel, visual-basic

I'm trying to figure out how to sort an Excel spreadsheet after part of the row is filled out. The last cell in a row is a formula to total up some of the other rows. The condition I was thinking about sorting the spreadsheet on was a change in the last cell. How would I detect if the last cell of the current row was changed by the formula and execute a sort macro?

Basically this is a form to track employee infractions, so the whole row isn't necessarily completely filled out unless they have multiple. I want to sort it based on the employee name. So far, I have it sort after you put in the employee's name, but that's kinda annoying when filling it out because you have to go find where that row went to continue. I'd prefer it sort after we finish adding an entry.

Comment: This use-case is a strong one for pitching storing this in a database instead of hamfisting Excel into doing it.  History tracking, which is what your requirement includes (even though it's just one record back) is one of the big red "let's talk database" flags.   You don't have to chase rows since data presents by query result, and you don't end up in hot water if you terminate an employee for infractions and they sue for wrongful termination, but all you have is an Excel sheet that could have been written up yesterday.

Comment: If there's a way to, I might be able to. Problem is that I can't host a database (my only experience is with MySQL), and I haven't used MS Access before. Part of the problem is that I'm not going to be able to maintain this after about 1-1.5 years. I'm a student manager, so I won't be here after I graduate. The next student manager might not be nearly as tech savvy, so I'm trying to make systems that are as easy to use as possible.

Comment: At the very least, I'd pick up Access.  It's not a "real" database from a programmer perspective (and we spend a lot of time converting them to real ones), but it's a database, and it works similarly to Excel in a lot of ways.  It's also a skill that if you're going to work in office environments, you're probably going to need.

Comment: I'm a programmer, so I can relate. I've spent the last couple of days learning VBA to code macros for this, but if an Access "database" is better, I'll look into it. I probably won't work in an office environment where I can't use SQL in the future, so I'm probably not going to need these skills in the future. Thank you!